# SQL Server - How can I remove row based on column value from previous date?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question about how to accomplish something in SQL Server. Basically, I want to take a set of data comes from a certain time period, and remove any rows where a column value, in this case SerialNumber, has been entered in the previous 3 weeks and has a passing mark. I filter based on the current date to return any potentially relevant entries. Below is that data.

[image: Data without removing unwanted row]

The issue is that the final entry in that above data has an entry date before the current date and in the previous 3 weeks time period, and it result has a pass of '1'. As such, I'd like to remove any entries for that SerialNumber value so it's not listed in today's results. The desired data is below.

[image: Desired Result]

Hopefully this makes sense to you guys. It's hard for me to describe. Current query Code is below, if needed. It doesn't make an attempt to implement the desired functionality as I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
Select * From
(SELECT A.SerialNumber
      ,[EndTime] as Date
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by A.SerialNumber order by EndTime desc) Entry
      ,[Pass]
      ,A.EntryTotal
      ,A.Passes
      ,CycleType

      From
        (
            SELECT max([SerialNumber]) as SerialNumber
            ,Count(*) as EntryTotal
            ,sum(convert(int,TD.Pass)) as Passes

            FROM [FlowDB2].[dbo].[TimeAnalyticsData] TD
            where Pass is not null
            group by SerialNumber
        ) 
        as A join [FlowDB2].[dbo].[TimeAnalyticsData] as TAD on A.SerialNumber = TAD.SerialNumber

        inner join [FlowDB2].[dbo].[TimeAnalytics] as TA on TAD.DurationID = TA.DurationID
        where 
        Pass is not null
        and
        (EndTime >= '2020-08-24 16:00:00' and EndTime < '2020-08-25 4:00:00')
        ) as B
```

Comment: Could you add your source data (not the result of your query) as a DDL statement to your question, so we can use it to better help you with your solution?

Comment: Lars' answer is pointing me in the right direction so it's not looking like it's necessary for this post, but I will be sure to do that moving forward with SQL posts as I was unaware that that was proper etiquette. My apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlated subquery allows you to compare data to itself.

The following looks for the non-existence of rows with the same SerialNumber as the current row with pass=1 less than 21 days ago.

The final filter simply makes sure you're looking at a different date than the current one.

```
select * 
from original_data od1
where not exists (select null
                  from original_data od2
                  where and od2.pass = 1
                   and od2.serialnumber = od1.serialnumber
                   and od2."Date" >  DATEADD(day, -21, od1.date)
                   and od2."Date" <> od1."Date"
                   );
```

with your original data recreated as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE original_data (
  "SerialNumber" BIGINT,
  "Date" datetime,
  "Entry" INTEGER,
  "Pass" INTEGER,
  "EntryTtl" INTEGER,
  "Passes" INTEGER,
  "CycleTy" VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO original_data
  ("SerialNumber", "Date", "Entry", "Pass", "EntryTtl", "Passes", "CycleTy")
VALUES
  ('6102046905', '2020-08-24 21:03:20.000', '1', '1', '2', '1', 'PA'),
  ('6102046905', '2020-08-24 19:47:23.000', '2', '0', '2', '1', 'PA'),
  ('6102046906', '2020-08-24 22:45:16.000', '1', '1', '2', '1', 'PA'),
  ('6102046906', '2020-08-24 19:47:23.000', '2', '0', '2', '1', 'PA'),
  ('6102047024', '2020-08-24 21:03:20.000', '1', '1', '2', '1', 'PA'),
  ('6102047024', '2020-08-24 19:47:23.000', '2', '0', '2', '1', 'PA'),
  ('6102047028', '2020-08-24 18:04:48.000', '1', '1', '2', '1', 'PA');
```

See how it works in [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aedf1b/7).

Comment: Huh, did not know this was a thing. Another tool for the toolbelt. Thanks!